Technology vs Business site category
Bitcoin is categorized as a business site
Monero and Ethereum are both categorized as technology sites
I can see the rational for both categories. How did Bitcoin compare the relative advantages of using one over the other?
I asked the same question in the Monero meta and am hoping an answer here can help guide us. Thank you!

No clue why it's "business", but it was even questioned already on Area51 in 2011.

Based on the prompting here and from the Bitcoin mods, we've gone ahead and changed the category to be Technology.  Not sure why it was categorized that way in the first place, but it's been updated. 
